# Using Javascript, how can I show a <tr> on top of another <tr> on hover, hiding the second <tr>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9u8tnh97/

I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap. I have a table with 4 `<tr>` elements like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="hover-data">
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
    </tr>

      <tr class="hover-link hide">
          <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Some link1</a></td>
      </tr>

    <tr class="hover-data">
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>

      <tr class="hover-link hide">
          <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Some link2</a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**And this is my Javascript:**

```
$('table tbody tr').hover(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('hover-data')){
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).prev().show();
        $(this).hide();        
    }
});
```

At first, I'm hiding the two rows with class `table-hover` by giving them a `hide` class and I'm only showing the ones with class `table-data`.

What I want to achieve: When I hover a `tr` with class `table-data`, I want the **next and immediate** `tr` with class `table-hover` to show and the "hovered tr" to hide.

When I move the mouse outside again I want everything to be restored and only see the `tr` with class `hover-data`

Not sure why my code won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Hiding the element that is hovered will probably stop the unhover event from ever occuring. Can you explain what the overall aim is (from the end-user's perspective) as I find the broken example confusing.

Comment: Yes, the user story is this: I have a list of names. When I hover of a particular person, I want to see a list of actions I can take, such as "Edit user", "Remove user" etc. I want this new list of actions to take same place as the users <tr>. Sort of like an overlay but on top of the <tr>. Did I clear it up?

Comment: May be your can fde the `<tr>` and show the *Edit/Remove* `<tr>` on top of it. Hiding would nullify hover.

Comment: I hope you know that in your jsfiddle example the bootstrap has an important on the display:none hide and so you won't be able to show it with a jquery .show(); This information will probably help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one uses `mouseenter` on the original rows and `mouseleave` on the new rows.

```
$('table tbody').on('mouseenter', 'tr.hover-data', function () {
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).hide();
}).on('mouseleave', 'tr.hover-link', function () {
    $(this).prev().show();).hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9u8tnh97/15/

I noticed that the bootstrap `hide` class is a little too "strong" and overrides `show()` so I also changed those to `style="display: none"` for now. Instead use your own class e.g. `hideme` in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9u8tnh97/17/

I am using delegated events (out of habit, and so they can share a common selector), but two separate "normal" (*static*) selectors will likely work just fine too. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9u8tnh97/16/

Comment: Perfect, this solves it, even if I don't like the inline style.

Comment: @Weblurk: Just use a class other than `hide`. The problem is it uses `!important` so even `show` won't show it. I will update the JSFiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9u8tnh97/17/

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
$('table tbody tr').hover(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('hover-data')){
        $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gqyrpnes/

Comment: You JSFiddle does not match your code (or work). Please sort out one or the other :)

Comment: This only shows it below. I can't even click the link. I want the previous tr to be replaced by the new one. And then when you hover outside again I want it to be restored..